# Converting a C Checksum Function to Lua

Tags: c, lua, bit-manipulation, checksum

I am writing a script to allow my host device to send data files to a slave device.  The slave requires a checksum calculation to be made and added to the end of my requests prior to sending the file(s).  My problem is that not only am I fairly new to programming, but I'm still trying to fully grasp bit manipulation.  I'm currently in a Java class so the checksum function so portions of the functions do have a familiar format, but since I'm still scratching my head with bits and the bit library, I'm having problems translating the provided checksum function into Lua.

The function is first described as follows prior to be provided the function in C:

```
Initialise the checksum as FFFF(hex).
For each byte
    Checksum = Checksum XOR (current Byte)
    For I = 0 to 7
        If ((Checksum AND 1)=0)
            Checksum = Right_Bit_Shift Checksum 1 bit
        Else
            Checksum = (Right_Bit_Shift Checksum 1 bit) XOR A001(hex)
        Next I
    Next Byte
```

Here is the example provided written in C:

```
/*
 *Routine CRC takes a data string (data) "length" long and *
 *   * returns the checksum value
 *
 *NOTE   WORD = unsigned short int
 *       BYTE = unsigned char
 */

WORD CRC( BYTE *data, WORD length)
{
    WORD sum = 65535;  /*Checksum value initialised to FFFFhex */
    while (length-- > 0)
    {
        sum = ByteCRC(sum, *data++ );
    }
    return sum;
}

WORD ByteCRC( WORD sum, BYTE data)
{
    WORD i;  /* Loop counter */
    sum = sum ^ (WORD)data;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if ( (sum&1) == 0)
            sum = sum>>1
        else
            sum = (sum >> 1) ^ 0xA001;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Now I'm currently enrolled in an intermediate Java class at school.  With that said, some portions of these functions I understand.  But as I said before, I'm still not fully understanding some aspects of bit manipulation in order to write these functions out into Lua format. I'm trying to recreate it myself in Lua but don't believe I'm correct or close.  Unfortunately, I do no understand the desired effect well enough to even try testing this out.  Here is what I've tried to write myself based on the information provided:

```
Function CRC(data, length)
    sum = 65535
    while length > 0 do
        sum = ByteCRC(sum, data=data+1)
        length = length - 1
    end
return sum
end

Function ByteCRC(sum, data)
    sum = sum ~ data
    for i = 0, 8 do
        if ((sum & 1) = 0)
            sum = sum >> 1
        else
            sum = (sum >> 1) ~ string.char(0xA001)
        end
    end
    return sum
end
```

Any critiquing and further assistance in helping me to A) write this better and B) find any errors in my translation is what I'm looking for.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @this I added a requrest to have the provided functions written similarly in Lua.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Present a specific problem please.

Comment: I can add my version written in Lua but am not fully understanding the first function that was written in C.

Comment: First of all, it isn't really good task for lua as it will run slow. Much better to define C function and bind it to lua. But if you absolutely have to - sure it is possible. If you don't know C operators - refer to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators). For lua conterpars - http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.7. After porting, test it on several data sets to ensure results remains the same for both languages. If you'll have problem with that - then post code you have. Or just google "lua bit32 crc", someone already done it.

Comment: I added my version written in Lua.

Comment: @this I understand and wasn't thinking of what I was truly asking until your post.  I should know better.  My fault.

Comment: @keltar I understand and have tried this.  Since I am familiar with Java, I have tried to do the conversion over from what I've learned in Java.  I have the Lua 5.3 manual bookmarked and used it to port the code over as best as I could.  With that said, I had no idea that this was done already.  I wasn't sure if this checksum calculation was something that could be specific to the slave device or it is a general calculation that ALL devices/software used.

Comment: Are you not getting an error at `string.char(0xA001)`: "bad argument #1 to 'char' (value out of range)"? Lua strings are counted sequences of bytes. Consider using a table sequence for your data.

Comment: @TomBlodget Awesome suggestion!  Hadn't crossed my inexperienced mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since lua have bit operations it is the same basic concept. Here how it goes, with some code comments:

```
function CRC(data, length)
    sum = 65535
    local d
    for i = 1, length do
        d = string.byte(data, i)    -- get i-th element, like data[i] in C
        sum = ByteCRC(sum, d)
    end
    return sum
end

function ByteCRC(sum, data)
    sum = sum ~ data
    for i = 0, 7 do     -- lua for loop includes upper bound, so 7, not 8
        if ((sum & 1) == 0) then
            sum = sum >> 1
        else
            sum = (sum >> 1) ~ 0xA001  -- it is integer, no need for string func
        end
    end
    return sum
end

print(CRC("foo", 3));
```

Comment: thank you for your example.  The notes help me understand the method behind your madness!  In line 4 of your example, `for i=1, length do` would it be ok to change the function to only accept the `data` argument and change that line to `for i=1, #data do` ?  That way I'm not having to worry about the length of the data coming into the function?

Comment: Yes, both `string.len` and `#` will do just fine.

Comment: great post.  I appreciate your help.  As I mentioned before, I should have added my version of the code in my original post so I didn't come off as just asking for code to be written for me by members of this site.   I'm also personally happy that I was able to get roughly 80% of the translation correct based on what I've learned in Java and Lua.  I may be retaining some information!  But your fine tuning of the code will assist me in better understanding why and how I should perform binary manipulation better, which is what I really want to do.