# Function with Checksum Function Producing nACK Responses

Tags: lua, checksum

For my current application, I'm writing up a plugin that will allow a device to speak to a slave device.  The slave device has two checksums, a header and a data checksum.  The header checksum was producing some erratic results which was fine tuned and corrected by members here:  [Odd Checksum Result(s) - Not Receiving Expected Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139593/odd-checksum-results-not-receiving-expected-results)

Now I'm unsure if my data checksum is correct.  I believe it is because of a thread that I had created here to help understand and build it which I did here:
[Converting a C Checksum Function to Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120322/converting-a-c-checksum-function-to-lua)

Now, I do not think that it is the data checksum functions.  But I believe it is the way I am trying to implement it.  I'm at the point where I'm now just trying to duplicate example code and send it to my slave device in hopes that I receive the appropriate response(s).  Problem is that I am receiving nACK's in return.  I've tried every permutation and combination I could think of and I'm not receiving an accepted value.  The `input` is a representation of the string I need to send to the `function databuild(str)` function below.

```
input = "010032380000000000000000000000000000000000000000"  -- title must be a specific length so it is filled with NUL's to meet that criteria

function CRC(data, length)
    sum = 65535
    local d
    for i = 1, length do
        d = string.byte(data, i)
        sum = ByteCRC(sum, d)
    end
    return sum
end

function ByteCRC(sum, data)
    sum = sum ~ data
    for i = 0, 7 do
        if ((sum & 1) == 0) then
            sum = sum >> 1
        else
            sum = (sum >> 1) ~ 0xA001
        end
    end
    return sum
end

function databuild(str) -- I know I should not be doing what's inside here but don't fully understand why not to and better ways of approaching it.
    local dataSum = ""
    local dataSumReslt = ""
    local dataConv = ""
    for char in str:gmatch("..") do
        dataConv = dataConv..string.char("0x"..char)
    end
    dataSum = string.format("%04X", CRC(dataConv, #dataConv))
    for char in dataSum:gmatch("..") do
        dataSumReslt = dataSumReslt..string.char("0x"..char)
    end
    return dataConv..dataSumReslt
end

print(databuild(input))
```

I'm supposed to be getting the data checksum based on those byte values in my print statement.  I send the entire string to the `function databuild(str)` function.  From there I turn the result to hex format and then concatenate that result (after turning the two-byte value to hex via `string.char`) and then return the entire hex string.

Right now, as it is, I get the result `170B`.  Unfortunately, I'm not advanced enough in programming to debug or test out properly whether what I'm receiving is true or not.

- Should I be turning the data string into hex first prior to doing the `function CRC(data, length)` or should I leave it the decimal representation first, or does it even matter???
- Since all 2-byte and 4-byte words within my files are needed to be little-endian, does it mean that my checksum should also be little-endian?  Or are checksums left untouched?  (the checksum functions were provided in C in the slave device's manual.
- Finally, what is a better way to approach the `function databuild(str)` so that I'm not breaking up each byte, translating it, then concatenating it so much?  I am very appreciative when my code is corrected.  But can someone help me understand exactly why it is just not a good thing to do?

Since I'm fairly new to programming in general, most of the time I'm not trying to work at this low-level (bit manipulation).  I haven't reached this point in any of my classes since it has been all higher-level programming (Java and self-taught what I know in Lua).  This is my first work project where it is truly "baptism by fire" concerning bytes, hex conversions, etc.  Needless to say I'm barely keeping my head above water here.  So all the constructive criticism I get is DEFINITELY wanted.

Comment: In `databuild`, shouldn't it be `return dataConv.. dataSumReslt` ?

Comment: @lhf you are correct.  I have no clue what I was or wasn't thinking.  Fixed my original post

Comment: @lhf or any other member for that matter, I plan on incorporating the code that lhf has provided below.  But I'd appreciate more input on two of my questions in my original post.  A) Should I turn the data string first from decimal to hex prior to sending the string to `function CRC(data, length)` or leave it decimal when sending?  And B) since all of the 2-byte and 4-byte words are little-endian, should the resulting checksum be altered in any way or leave the end result unaltered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace

```
for char in str:gmatch("..") do
    dataConv = dataConv..string.char("0x"..char)
end
```

with

```
dataConv = str:gsub("..",function (x) return string.char(tonumber(x,16)) end)
```

You can simplify this to

```
dataConv = str:gsub("..",HEX)
```

after doing

```
HEX={}
for c=0,255 do
    HEX[string.format("%02x",c)] = string.char(c)
end
```

This will avoid the concatenations.

Comment: Can you or someone please explain to me why it is best to avoid the concatenation(s) that I am doing?  Is simply because it takes up additional resources to maintain all of manipulations being performed to create each byte?  Or does it have to do with bit manipulations in general?  I want to understand this better please.

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 Every concatenation of strings requires allocating & copying both parts into a new string. Hence, repeated concatenation results in significant overhead and a lot of garbage that has to be freed by the garbage collector. Using `table.concat` to concatenate many pieces at once will avoid most of that overhead, same goes for using `string.gsub` & co and making them replace parts while traversing. (Low-level Info: These use a `luaL_Buffer` (http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_Buffer) that grows incrementally and avoids most of the copying.)

Comment: @nobody Awesome info.  I'll read more into the `luaL_Buffer` that you mention to obtain a better understanding.

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 Well, you usually don't need to know about that unless you're working on the C side. (And even then, only if you need to manually combine many strings – often, you can let `asprintf` and others to do the combining for you.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you had problem with MarkemImaje printer.

You have a mistake here:

`sum = (sum >> 1) ~ 0xA001 --> sum = (sum >> 1) ^ 0xA001`